# A sqlcmd script in windows10 stop run after accessing the data

Tags: sql, sql-server, batch-file, windows-10

sorry for my SQL noobization but cant pass this simple problem when running script with SQL sqlcmd in windows10.
I try to run a simple batch script to print to the command prompt the SQL table content however after the script reach the point where he enter the SQL table he stop running the next commands which are the query and go.

```
sqlcmd -S . -U sa -P 1111 -d MyDataBase
select * from customersOrders
go
```

running the command from the script 1 by 1 in the command prompt work well but running it as a whole in script it stop in the select command.

Comment: If you're just trying to run one command, look at the -Q option to SQLCMD. If you're trying to run more than one, I'd suggest putting all of the SQL commands (and just those; not the call to sqlcmd itself) in a file and passing that to sqlcmd with the -i option.

Comment: thanks! it did the trick